# GKPlayerInternal setAuthenticateHandler for both iOS4.3 and iOS6 ?

Tags: ios6

Get error SIGABRT with this log: "-[GKPlayerInternal setAuthenticateHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

I test this on iPad 3 iOS 5.1.1

GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)  //error here
{ /* some code */ };
On iOS 6 this work fine , I know setAuthenticateHandler: is only available on iOS6 , but how can I support both iOS5 and iOS6  at same time ?